# How to convert AVI to 3gp in C#?

Tags: c#, avi, 3gp

Is it possible to convert an AVI file to 3gp in C# ? If so how could I do this? Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: How on earth did this question get 4 upvotes. Please read the tooltip that you get when you hover over the up arrow

Answer (score 6):

It depends what you mean by "convert". Both 3GP and AVI are wrapper formats, so are you merely trying to change the container format, or do you want to re-encode the streams as well?

Either way, you should probably take a look at [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) ([Windows info](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/)). For simple cases (i.e. you have the file, want a single output file), you should probably consider it invoking it on the command-line (i.e. [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)), which is much easier (and doesn't involve any licensing issues). If you want to access libavcodec/libavormat programatically, I ***highly*** recommend skipping any .NET wrapper libs (they all are in different states of sucking; [Tao](http://sourceforge.net/projects/taoframework/) being the best but that's not saying much) and instead writing a [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) wrapper. I [started doing this](http://www.assembla.com/code/mime/subversion/nodes/trunk/mime.transcode.ffmpeg/src?rev=352), and once I got my head around data marshalling, etc., and figured out how to build it ([Part 1](http://www.assembla.com/code/mime/subversion/nodes/trunk/deps/ffmpeg/README.txt?_format=raw&rev=352), [Part 2](http://www.assembla.com/code/mime/subversion/nodes/trunk/deps/ffmpeg/build.mime.sh?rev=352#)), it wasn't too hard.

Answer (score 0):

There is no really easy way to do it; my advice is to use ffmpeg, either through the use of a C# wrapper of by calling it externally. There seem to be several C# wrappers for ffmpeg (like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/)) but they all seem to be in various stages of development and not really usable. Your only option is likely going to be by calling it externally.

Comment: ffmpeg-sharp is incomplete and old. Have you had any success with it? I've found Tao to be a bit better, but ended up directly calling it through a C++/CLI wrapper.

Comment: It was essentially useless for most things - like I advised, I ended up using the system ffmpeg and piping to/from. Less control but enough for a simple conversion between container formats.