# convert 'avi' to '3gp'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

1. How can I convert `avi` (or and any other video file) to `3gp` in .net.
   Preferably in `asp.net4`.
2. If a site  is blocked by name and IP by the ISP, is it possible to write a method to download files and get the HTML of the site being blocked (rejected).

Answer (score 0):

For the Part #1 of the question:

*It depends what you mean by "convert". Both 3GP and AVI are wrapper formats, so are you merely trying to change the container format, or do you want to re-encode the streams as well?* ****[Quoted]***

Please this Question for more details:

[How to convert AVI to 3gp in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799024/how-to-convert-avi-to-3gp-in-c)